# Using VI how can I search and replace for the following statement?

Tags: regex, vi

I need to replace the following:

```
CREATE TABLE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `access`
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `access`
```

I've tried

```
:%s/\/\*\!\d+(.*)\*\//\1/g
```

But that didn't seem to go. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vim requires backslashing + (or use * instead). Also, you need to backslash grouping parenthesis in vim. Thus:

```
:%s/\/\*\!\d\+\(.*\)\*\//\1/g
```

Yes, vim's old-style posix regexes suck :/

Edit: As mentioned in the comments below, + does work if escaped as \+. And \d actually is supported, oops. Edited the example regex to correct for this. Also see Brian Carper's example for a more succinct and readable version.

Comment: vim does support +, you just have to escape it, "\+"

Comment: Apparently it does. Awesome. I still want a PCRE-for-vim plugin though :)

Comment: Just deleted my answer: it turns out I do not know enough about the regex support specifics in Vim ;)

Comment: You might as well edit the answer to make it up-vote-able and accept-able

Comment: @Nathan This answer works just fine, but the extra comments are also great to have. Thanks all.

Comment: u can use + instead of \+ using \v (very magic) option. check :h \v in vim

Answer (score 4):

Use "very magic", and use delimiters other than the default to make this easier to read (and remember).

```
:%s@\v/\*!\d+(.*)\*/@\1@g
```

Without "very magic" you have to put a backslash in front of `+` and `()` (but not in front of `*` or some other things).  It's not very consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different and more efficient with [^*]+  :-)

```
1,$s/\v\/\*\!\d+\s*([^*]+)\*\//\1
```